# Bitwise operations on a short

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm using a short (and I must use a short for the assignment otherwise I would just use an int) to scan in a value between 0-31 and then using a single integer to store 6 of these scanned values.

This is what I have so far:

```
int vals = 0;
short ndx, newVal;

/* more printing/scanning and error checking in between */

newVal = newVal << (5*ndx);
vals = vals | newVal;
```

When I try to place a valid value at spot 4 or 5 it doesn't work and just stays 0... I'm wondering if this is because a short is only 2 bytes long so the bitwise left shift just gets rid of the entire value? And if this is the problem is there some sort of cast I can add to fix it?

Comment: That's possibly because `short` is no more than 20 bits (e. g. 16) on your system. Use `uint32_t` (`uint_least32_t` / `uint_fast32_t`) for 32-bit cardinals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly what you thought. You used a bitwise-shift, and then assigned the result into a short variable (newVal). When you do that, even if the calculation is done in 32-bit, the result still gets truncated, and you only get the least significant 16 bits of 0s.

If you want to refrain from using an int, just drop the newVal variable completely, and calculate `vals = vals | ((something) << (some other thing));`